# Оживить страницу html

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, site

Я написал шахматы на js, подключил GH pages и сайт работает, но как добавить взаимодействие с другими посетителями сайта?Чтобы у меня была одна и та же доска, что и у другого пользователя. Для начала просто хотелось бы понять как сделать сайт "одинаковым для всех пользователей", а дальше уже при необходимости буду смотреть как разделять на пары и т.д. Сори вопрос очень просто, но сколько видео я не смотрю я не могу понять с чего вообще начать и что нужно добавить.

Comment: Нужно добавить сервер, на котором будет храниться состояние этой самой доски. На GH pages сделать это не получится

Comment: Ну или можно соединить двух пользователей друг с другом напрямую через WebRTC и на сервере ничего не хранить, но опять же для организации соединения всё равно нужен сервер

Comment: т.е. gh pages только для статичных веб страниц максимум может подойти, правильно? И если не сложно, то можно описать что именно нужно будет сделать с кодом или про что почитать, для такого динамического изменения страницы на сервере